# WPF Shadow Effects

Tags: wpf, xaml, shadow

I am trying to replicate a screen made by designers through code but I am having trouble with a shadow effect that they have included in the design. This is the shadow effect they have implemented:

[image]

I have made an attempt at this using drop shadow in XAML - but it doesn't seem right for my requirement. As the designer's shadow looks more like there is a vertical light on the object and the drop shadow looks more like the object is popping out of the screen.

[image]

Is there a way of implementing the first shadow effect through WPF?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can get result 1 by changing properties of the shadow effect that is implemented by wpf. But if not you still can create a custom effect. You can find a lot of articles on internet. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71617/Getting-Started-with-Shader-Effects-in-WPF

Comment: whats the problem just change the Blurradius and the Shadowdeph and you ll get your result

Comment: I played around with the Blurradius and ShadowDepth of DropShadow and was unable to get this to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to play around a bit to get it right (`Margin`s, etc.), but I would try using a `BlurEffect` on a filled rectangle to emulate the shadow:

```
<Grid>

  <!-- shadow -->
  <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    Height="..." Fill="#77000000" ... >
    <Rectangle.Effect>
      <BlurEffect ... />
    </Rectangle.Effect>
  </Rectangle>

  <!-- white border on top of shadow -->
  <Border Background="#ffffff" ... >
    <!-- other controls -->
  </Border>

</Grid>
```